# How to use onchange event?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

This is my code where if i put quantity then it will calculate it and show it in total amount. my problem is that if i change my quantity in between process my total amount is not change.

How to do it `onchange` quantity total amount have to different

```js
<script> 
  function valid(obj)
  {
   var frm=document.getElementById("frm");
   var qty=parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
   var price=parseInt(obj.value);
   var total=parseInt(document.getElementById("total").value);
   if(isNaN(total))
   {
    total=0;
   }
   if(obj.checked==true)
   {
    total=total+(qty*price);
    document.getElementById("total").value=total;
   }
   else
   {
    total=total-(qty*price);
    document.getElementById("total").value=total;
   }
   /*for(var i=0;i<frm.length;i++)
   {
    if(frm[i].type=="checkbox")
    {
     if(frm[i].checked==true)
     {
      total=total+(parseInt(frm[i].value)*qty);
     }
    }
   }*/
   document.getElementById("total").value=total
  }   
 </script>
```

```html
<form action="abc.html" method="post" id="frm" onsubmit="return valid(this);">
 <table>
  <tr> 
   <th colspan="2">Qualification</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="1000" onClick="valid(this);" /></td><td>BCA</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="2000" onClick="valid(this);" /></td><td>MCA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="1200" onClick="valid(this);" /></td><td>BBA</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="1000" onClick="valid(this);" /></td><td>MBA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="" placeholder="Total"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><input type="button" onClick="valid();" name="submit" value="Send" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>  
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `in between process` ?

Comment: if i put any value like 1 in quantity and check on any checkbox it will display amount of that field in total amount textbox.

Comment: but now i want to change quantity to 2 from 1 then total amount of that field should be change automatically . but it is not happeing in my form

Comment: did `spankajd` answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `var isFormSubimited = false;` 
Set `isFormSubimited = true` in valid function.

Add "`onchange='onQuantityChange()'`" to quantity input element.

Add following function.

```
function onQuantityChange()
{
  if(isFormSubimited && $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length > 0)
  {
    //var _form = document.getElementById('frm');
    //_form.submit();
    valid();
  } 
}
```

Comment: its working bro. but its not working if i checked all chechbox and then change quantity . it should be works if i checked all chechbox already and then change quantity total amount should be also change

Comment: @AMITSUTARMUMBAIKAR you means all checkbox must be selected or at least one checkbox ??
if 0 checkbox is selected then it should not work right ??

Comment: ya right bro. if i select any checkbox then total amount should be change

Comment: $("input[type='checkbox']:checked") is added in if condition try with this and let me know

Comment: 3 chechbox with their unique price comes from database in array. if i put 1 in quantity and choose first chechbox then its price should be display in total amount. its working but now if i change my quantity from 1 to 2 then that checked chechbox's value is not changing plz help me

Comment: your code is working on unchecked values .i want to change checked values

Comment: Hi this not related to above question, so please add new question for this ;) .